# Active track Profile and Spotlight Not working in Phantom 4

Tags: dji-sdk

Platform : Android
DJI MSDK: 4.8.1

Active Track Profile and Spotlight is not working in Phantom 4. It gives the following error "Param Invalid" , "The command is not supported by the current firmware".

I have upgraded the firmware to the latest version.